# Hartl's sample_app warning on config.serve_static_files, and test already defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am trying to test Hartl's sample_app and this is message that I get after running `bundle exec rake test`:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in <top (required)> at /home/aki/sample_app/config/environments/test.rb:16)
rake aborted!
test_should_be_valid is already defined in UserTest
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb:14:in `test'
/home/aki/sample_app/test/models/user_test.rb:10:in `<class:UserTest>'
/home/aki/sample_app/test/models/user_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is `test/integration/users_profile_test.rb` file.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersProfileTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include ApplicationHelper

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "profile display" do
    get user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select 'title', full_title(@user.name)
    assert_select 'h1', text: @user.name
    assert_select 'h1>img.gravatar'
    assert_match @user.microposts.count.to_s, response.body
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    @user.microposts.paginate(page: 1).each do |micropost|
      assert_match micropost.content, response.body
    end
  end
end
```

And this is `sample_app/config/environments/test.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.serve_static_assets  = true
  config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=3600'

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
  # Randomize the order test cases are executed.
  config.active_support.test_order = :random

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

This is `test/models/user_test.rb`.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end


  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                         first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
  end

  test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                           foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
  end

  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end

  test "password should have a minimum length" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
    assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
  end

test "associated microposts should be destroyed" do
    @user.save
    @user.microposts.create!(content: "Lorem ipsum")
    assert_difference 'Micropost.count', -1 do
      @user.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

I am just walking trough instructions from tutorial so I don't know what I am doing wrong.. If you need some other files, I will post them..
Are gem versions different maybe or is it something else?

Comment: Warnings are not errors. It clearly states that nothing will happen if you follow instructions and specify versions provided in your tutorial. Major versions are bumped (i. e. 4.2 to 5.0) when compatibility is broken. This is just a friendly reminder for developers that plan to upgrade in the future. Keep calm and carry on :)

Answer (score 5):

The tutorial is outdated. Your output message shows two issues.

#### 1. Deprecation Warning

The deprecation warning is shows that `serve_static_assets` is an old name, and the new name is `serve_static_files`. Rails makes steady improvements to names and methods, so this is a pretty common warning.

Edit `sample_app/config/environments/test.rb`.

From this:

```
config.serve_static_assets  = true
```

To this:

```
config.serve_static_files  = true
```

#### 2. Test redefined

The second issue is that there's a problem with your test file.

Look at the error message and see the top line that is about your code:

```
/home/aki/sample_app/test/models/user_test.rb:10:in `<class:UserTest>'
```

Can you post this file please?

The error message is saying that you've defined a method twice.

#### Verify

To verify your changes are in place, `cd` to your Rails root directory.

Find file names that contain the old assets setting:

```
find -type f | xargs grep -l 'serve_static_assets'
```

Find file names that contain the method name text:

```
find -type f | xargs grep -l 'test.*should.*be.*valid'
```

Look at any files that turn up, and see if there is code that still needs to be changed, or perhaps if there is a test "should be valid" in another UserTest class.

Comment: I have already tried with renaming to config.serve_static_files, but that doesn't change result. Also, i have updated question with user_test.rb file now. Thanks Joel..

Comment: Double-check that you're saving the files, i.e. File -> Save. I know it sounds trivial, yet the output messages do not seem to match the files you're posting. Double-check that you don't have any other UserTest class defined, in any other file. Double-check that your other config/environments/*.rb files are also changed from serve_static_assets to serve_static_files.

Comment: I don't know what is problem. I checked everything you said I should, all seems ok but problem is still there.. Can you tell me where is this file? /home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb:14:in  And where is this method defined: test_associated_microposts_should_be_destroyed? Console says that method is in UserTest class, but it isn't..

Comment: That file is at that path, i.e. /home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/testi‌​ng/declarative.rb (but I'd be surprised if the problem is in that file). The method `test_associated_microposts_should_be_destroyed?` is defined in UserTest, by the line `test "associated microposts should be destroyed"` (the `test` word converts its string name to a method name automatically)

Comment: I should see that :) Do you have any other sugestion where to look? Thanks for this so far..

Comment: Yes, I just added more to the answer to help you search for any items that still need fixing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find `serve_static_assets` in one of your config files, it's likely that one gem is setting this options. So do it:

```
bundle update
```

It solved my problem