# Errors on all tests using sample_app from rubyonrailstutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I completed the sample_app from Hartl's rubyonrailstutorial about 6 months ago and then put it down.  I went to run it today and now I seem to be getting errors related to the "setup" function in my tests.  There are 45 errors - I'll post 3 of them below:

```
ERROR["test_should_redirect_create_when_not_logged_in", MicropostsControllerTest, 2015-05-17 12:55:23 -0400]
 test_should_redirect_create_when_not_logged_in#MicropostsControllerTest (1431881723.02s)
ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
            test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:6:in `setup'
        test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:6:in `setup'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_destroy_for_wrong_micropost", MicropostsControllerTest, 2015-05-17 12:55:23 -0400]
 test_should_redirect_destroy_for_wrong_micropost#MicropostsControllerTest (1431881723.02s)
ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
            test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:6:in `setup'
        test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:6:in `setup'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in", MicropostsControllerTest, 2015-05-17 12:55:23 -0400]
 test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in#MicropostsControllerTest (1431881723.03s)
ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
            test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:6:in `setup'
        test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:6:in `setup'
```

Here is the **micropost_controller_test.rb**:

```
require 'test_helper'

class MicropostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @micropost = microposts(:orange)   #THIS IS LINE 6
  end

  test "should redirect create when not logged in" do
    assert_no_difference 'Micropost.count' do
      post :create, micropost: { content: "Lorem ipsum" }
    end
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect destroy when not logged in" do
    assert_no_difference 'Micropost.count' do
      delete :destroy, id: @micropost
    end
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect destroy for wrong micropost" do
    log_in_as(users(:thomas))
    micropost = microposts(:ants)
    assert_no_difference 'Micropost.count' do
      delete :destroy, id: micropost
    end
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

end
```

Here is the **microposts.yml** file in the fixtures folder (you'll note that I replaced 'michael' with 'thomas':

```
orange:
  content: "I just ate an orange!"
  created_at: <%= 10.minutes.ago %>
  user: thomas

tau_manifesto:
  content: "Check out the @tauday site by @mhartl: http://tauday.com"
  created_at: <%= 3.years.ago %>
  user: thomas

cat_video:
  content: "Sad cats are sad: http://youtu.be/PKffm2uI4dk"
  created_at: <%= 2.hours.ago %>
  user: thomas

most_recent:
  content: "Writing a short test"
  created_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
  user: thomas

<% 30.times do |n| %>
micropost_<%= n %>:
  content: <%= Faker::Lorem.sentence(5) %>
  created_at: <%= 42.days.ago %>
  user: thomas
<% end %>

ants:
  content: "Oh, is that what you want? Because that's how you get ants!"
  created_at: <%= 2.years.ago %>
  user: archer

zone:
  content: "Danger zone!"
  created_at: <%= 3.days.ago %>
  user: archer

tone:
  content: "I'm sorry. Your words made sense, but your sarcastic tone did not."
  created_at: <%= 10.minutes.ago %>
  user: lana

van:
  content: "Dude, this van's, like, rolling probable cause."
  created_at: <%= 4.hours.ago %>
  user: lana
```

Here is the **micropost.rb** model,

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validate  :picture_size

  private

    # Validates the size of an uploaded picture.
    def picture_size
      if picture.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB")
      end
    end
end
```

Here is the **microposts_controller.rb**:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

Here is the **gemfile.rb**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.1'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0.beta4'     #<<<THIS WAS THE PROBLEM.  ANSWER BELOW
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'faker', '1.4.2'
#Items for image upload
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'

gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.0.beta2'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.3'
gem 'rails-html-sanitizer', '1.0.1'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0',          group: :doc


group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'unicorn',                '4.8.3'
end
```

Although Hartl consistently states that we should use the exact gem versions from the tutorial, I did update the ruby version from 2.1 to 2.2 and I explicitly call it in my gem file.

**Ruby version:** ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin13]

**Rails version:** Rails 4.2.0.beta4

**System:**  Mac OS X Version 10.9.5

I recently installed mysql to my Mac, but I'm not using it in the sample_app.  The sample_app uses sqlite as recommended in the tutorial.  I made sure that an instance of mysql is not running at the time.

The statement "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" is consistent in every error.  Also, every error appears to occur at the "setup"  method.

This app worked fine 6 months ago.  Any suggestions on why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Try changing `@micropost = microposts(:orange) ` to `@micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user.id)` with the appropriate initialization of `user` variable. Creating the micro post object directly this way instead of using the fixtures could show a new error trace, and help identify the issue.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried this and several other alternatives.  Didn't work.  After hours of research all I had to do was update my rails gem.  I'm posting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the version of Rails used in 'sample_app'.  In fairness to Hartl, he repeatedly states that we should use the configuration & gem versions shown in the tutorial.

I changed

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.0.beta4’
```

to

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.1’
```

Then I ran `bundle update`

I ran `bundle exec rake test`, and *voila!*, no errors.
This solved the error problem in my original post, but then I received the following warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option
>   `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to
>   `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables
>   serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the
>   asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in
>   Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly.
>   (called from block in  at
>   [.....]/sample_app/config/environments/test.rb:16)

This required an update to the /config/environments/test.rb file.  Changed
`config.serve_static_assets  = true`
to
`config.serve_static_files  = true`

See the following link for more info on the solution:
[Hartl's sample_app warning on config.serve_static_files, and test already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415821/hartls-sample-app-warning-on-config-serve-static-files-and-test-already-define)