# heroku 'serve_static_assets' issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm having a trouble pushing to heroku; I keep getting:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in tsort_each at /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226)
```

(also just saw it again as this):

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in tsort_each at /tmp/build_c9447e81993b6aaa7ea4e3f42707ac87/vendor/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226)
```

Now I've read things such as [Hartl's sample_app warning on config.serve_static_files, and test already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415821/hartls-sample-app-warning-on-config-serve-static-files-and-test-already-define) and I've searched through my app and don't have it set; HOWEVER in my Gemfile.lock:

```
rails_serve_static_assets
```

219        rails_stdout_logging
  220:     rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)

Could that be the issue?  Should I delete the .lock and bundle install again now that in my production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

Wondering if I should upgrade to 2.2.2 : patchlevel 95, Rubygems: ; 2.4.5

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find `serve_static_assets` in one of your config files, it's likely that one gem (probably rails_serve_static_assets) is setting this option. So do it:

```
bundle update rails_serve_static_assets
```

or generally:

```
bundle update
```

The second one will update all of your gems.
It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In `your_app/config/environments/production.rb` under `Rails.application.configure do` add this:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

Comment: But I've already got config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?  and in the heroku config vars they automatically add RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES => enabled; so wouldn't that be the same thing?